# Error de configuración "CrystalDecisions.Web.dll"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, webforms, web.config

Porque hay conflicto si el archivo CrystalDecisions.Web.dll ya lo tengo en Referencias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Web.Config**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Para obtener más información sobre cómo configurar la aplicación de ASP.NET, visite
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true"/>
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000"/>
    <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000"/>
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    Para obtener una descripción de los cambios de web.config para .NET 4.5, vea http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    Los siguientes atributos se pueden establecer en la etiqueta <httpRuntime>.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="es-PE" uiCulture="es-PE" fileEncoding="utf-8"/>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/> <!--AQUÍ SALE ERROR-->
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc"
          type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="2880" requireSSL="true"/>
    </authentication>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="60"/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx"
        type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*"
        type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"
        validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="Login.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <handlers>
      <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx"
        type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
        preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
        type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Revisate estos enlaces: [definición de manifiesto](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/53b51e0b-6784-4d2c-be13-645fe9cfc9a8/la-definicin-de-manifiesto-del-ensamblado-no-coincide-con-la-referencia-de-ensamblado?forum=netfxwebes) y [HRESULT: 0x80131040](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93879/hresult-0x80131040-the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-t)

Comment: Nada amigo @OrlandoDeLaRosa, ¿alguna otra idea que tengas?, solo tengo ese problema.

Comment: Pues si te fijas el error que te marca te dice `HRESULT: 0x80131040` los enlaces hablan de lo mismo solo que con diferentes librerias.

Comment: Dentro de tu solucion cuantos proyectos tienes y cuantos a puntan a esa libreria?

Comment: tbn puedes poner en google `HRESULT: 0x80131040 CrystalDecisions.Web`

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa solo un proyecto.

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal, ¿cuál es la versión de `CrystalDecisions.Web.dll`?. Yo tuve un problema similar al descargar un proyecto que implementa CrystalReports y, luego de instalar el componente de SAP y reiniciar el equipo, no tuve mas problemas. Puede que esto sea algo de la caché de la dll. ¿Este problema ya lo tenías antes?

Comment: Para nada, primera vez. Y la versión de mi CrystalDecisions.Web.dll es 11.5.3700.0.

Comment: Probaré reiniciando como tu me indicas @MauricioAriasOlave

Comment: Ya reinicie mi equipo y sigue igual :(

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal ¿cuál es la versión de `CrystalDecisions.Web.dll`?, ¿`CrystalDecisions.Web.dll` está en la carpeta "bin"?, otra opción "solo es para probar" es: modifique el web.config póngale una versión superior * - (en este caso, 14.0)* y ejecute. pregunto nuevamente: ¿Este problema ya lo tenías antes?, ¿hubo algún cambio que hiciste, descargaste otra versión del programa o algo así?. [edit] la pregunta con la respuesta a estas interrogantes.

Comment: Si te respondí a la pregunta amigo @MauricioAriasOlave, Para nada, primera vez. Y la versión de mi CrystalDecisions.Web.dll es 11.5.3700.0. –

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal ¿Cambió en el web.config para que diga la versión (11.5)? limpie y recompile la solución. Asegúrese que la dll esté en la carpeta "bin". El error es porque tienes la versión 11.5, pero en el web.config dice que es la versión 13.0.

Comment: EFECTIVAMENTE MI ESTIMADO @MauricioAriasOlave, muchas gracias por ayudarme en este gran problema que resulto ser pequeño, jeje.

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal que bueno que sea la solución, voy a publicar la respuesta para que así se pueda dar una solución formal *(aceptando la respuesta)*. Saludos.

Comment: Claro, pon la respuesta y le daré en aceptar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo que [comentas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/229658/error-de-configuraci%C3%B3n-crystaldecisions-web-dll?noredirect=1#comment426723_229658) en tu pregunta, la versión de `CrystalDecisions.Web.dll` que tienes es la versión *13.0*.

La versión registrada en el archivo `web.config` de tu aplicación es (para la dll `CrystalDecisions.Web.dll`) la versión *11.5*.

El cambio que debes hacer es: actualizar el archivo `web.config` para aplicar el número de la versión que realmente posees, es decir, la versión *13.0*.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente, no tengo mucha experiencia con el CrystalReports, pero gracias a ti iré aprendiendo de poco en poco. Saludos.

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal no hay problema, todos estamos para aprender y compartir experiencias. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la respuesta, se me presentó el mismo problema con CrystalDecisions.Web; comparo la versión del web.config y la dll existente en referencias, no concordaba. Procedo a actualizar el web.config y todo bien.

**Ejemplo dll referenciada, en mi caso:**

[image: ejemplo de mi versión en referencias...]

**web.config modificado:**

```
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
```